# Degree sequences in self-complementary graphs

Tags: graph-theory

If a graph $G$ is *self-complementary* and if ($d_1 ,d_2 ,\ldots,d_n$) is the degree sequence of $G$, then what is:

- $d_i + d_{n+1-i}$ for all  $i \leq n/2$

I am confused what by it means? Any hint?

Comment: What is the definition of self-complementary? Please try to make your question as complete as possible.

Comment: A self-complementary graph $G$ is isomorphic to its complement.  The complement of a graph is one where every edge is deleted and every pair of vertexes that isn't connected is now connected by an edge.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I just don't understand the notation and what does the question wants me to find, I understand well what is a self-complementary graph.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If $G$ has $n$ vertices, and $\bar{G}$ is its complement, then for each vertex you have
$$\deg_{G}(v)+\deg_{\bar{G}}(v)=n-1$$

Answer (score 2):

If the degree of vertex $i$ is $d_i$, then its degree in the complement is $n - d_i - 1$.